Taking the finite and infinite sum of an inequality
I am considering the inequality
$$ 
|x_j| \leq |y_j| + |z_j|, 
$$
where each of these series $(j=1,2, \dots)$ are comprised of complex numbers.
If I take finite sum $(j = 1, \dots, n)$ of this inequality I was told that the inequality is preserved (related to the finite sum being a linear operator).
Furthermore, if both of the resulting sequences of partial sums converge, I can take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and obtain the inequality for the related series.
Can someone help me understand how the inequality is preserved under finite addition? It is probably something simple I am missing!
Thanks in advance!

Adding finitely many finite things gives a finite thing. Not so true for infinitely many finite things.

If $a_1\le b_1+c_1$ and $a_2\le b_2+c_2$, then $a_1+a_2\le b_1+b_2+c_1+c_2$. Is this what you're asking for?
